# How to display alert dialog in any activity in android application?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my application I want to display common `AlertDialog` for all activities.
In my background thread, Server data is coming periodically.

Now if some user defined criteria are matched with that data, I want to display `AlertDialog` on screen in any activity which is currently on front.

How can I identify that where to display `AlertDialog` ?
And if my application is in background, I want to set `Notifications` rather than `AlertDialog`.

Comment: You need the help, to display AlertDialog in your Class??

Comment: Have you considered using Fragments instead of multiple activities in your application? Fragments have their own lifecycle within the lifecycle of their parent Activity. So if you have one main activity and many fragments working within that activity, you can always use the main Activity context within your various fragments, to display an AlertDialog

Answer (score -1):

You can show alert dialog from background by any one of below...

But before your show dialog you need to check if activity is running or not by using one boolean flag as below otherwise you will get `WindowManager$BadTokenException`.

```
// Flag to check if activity is running or not
boolean isActivityRunning = false;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isActivityRunning = true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    isActivityRunning = false;
}
```

**1. runOnUiThread**

You need to show your dialog on UI thread like below...

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               if(isActivityRunning) {
                 // Your dialog code.
                 AlertDialog ActiveCallDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setMessage(R.string.message)                       
                    .setTitle(R.string.title)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();
               }    
            }
        });
```

**2. Handler**

You can create an handler in Activity Class, and can invoke sendMessage to that handler object. Write code to display alert in handleMessage method of Handler, for Example:

**Activity Class**

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler()
{
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
       if(isActivityRunning) {
          //Display Alert
          AlertDialog ActiveCallDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setMessage(R.string.message)                       
                    .setTitle(R.string.title)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();             
        }            
    }
};
```

**Thread**

```
Thread thread= new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {             
         mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: The application context is not always suitable for AlertDialogs. You can get a `WindowManager$BadTokenException` exception: `Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`.